# instanceof operator in case of primitive and wrapper type array

Tags: java, arrays, object, instanceof, scjp

```
int primitivI[] = {1,1,1};
Integer wrapperI[] = {2,22,2};


1. System.out.println(primitivI instanceof Object);//true
2. System.out.println(primitivI instanceof Object[]);//Compilation Error Why ????
3. System.out.println(wrapperI  instanceof Object);//true
4. System.out.println(wrapperI  instanceof Object[]);//true
```

Here I have two arrays of integer (primitve,Wrapper) type but I have got different result for
instanceof operator

see the line number 2 and 4 
line no 4 will compile successfully and give result true but in case of line 2, why does it result in a compilation error?
From line 1 and 3 it is clear that the two arrays are instanceof object but in case of `Object[]`, why do the 
results differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JLS 15.20.2.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) says :

> If a cast of the RelationalExpression to the ReferenceType would be rejected as a compile-time error, then the instanceof relational expression likewise produces a compile-time error. In such a situation, the result of the instanceof expression could never be true.

That means that if at compile time the compiler knows that X cannot be instanceof Y, the expression `X instanceof Y` would give a compile time error.

You can get simpler examples that don't compile, without trying with arrays :

```
String s = "dgd";
System.out.println(s instanceof Integer);
```

Similarly, your 2nd example doesn't compile, since `int[]` cannot be cast to `Object[]`. All your other examples compile, since `primitivI` can be cast to `Object` and `wrapperI` can be cast to both `Object` and `Object[]`.

Comment: thanks..but if primitivI is instanceof Object then why its not an instance of Object[]..where the same case is true for wrapperI

Comment: @Nirav primitivel is an array, and therefore can be cast to an Object,  since an array is an Object.  It cannot be cast to Object[], because it's an array of primitive type, so it can't be cast to an array of Object.

Comment: got it ...if i take int a = 10 and then check with instanceof then it will also give me compilation error. here i am checking with array to instanceof Object so thats why it gives me result true